# Is it a good practice to redirect after a form has been submitted?

Tags: php, redirect

I've recently taken to doing a header() redirect (to the same page) after certain forms on my website have been submitted (mostly related to a shopping cart application) so that the user doesn't do unintended things by refreshing the page or by going "back" or "forward" and refreshing the page. Is this an acceptable practice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is standard practice called `redirect after post` or [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). It's considered best practice when dealing with post forms

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a good practice. It makes things much friendlier to the user. It's also probably the second-best solution, in fact (the first, of course, being to use Ajax primarily)! Just make sure to only do it on success.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think much of using `header()` to accomplish it, but I think that's a great practice.

As minitech said, make sure you only do it on success. Otherwise re-render your form with the appropriate error messages shown.

Comment: I accept that I should keep my bias against PHP out of my answer, but I think drive-by down-voters also should keep their bias out of their votes. I've edited my answer, so let's see those go away.