# Do I need to create a completely new view for my success page?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a form, and when the user submits valid information (clicking the 'submit' button on the page), I currently have a redirect to a success page occur.

```
class PostAdPage(CreateView):
    template_name = 'post_ad.html'
    success_url = '/awesome/'
    form_class = PostAdForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return HttpResponse("Awesome.")
```

I don't want the redirect to occur. Instead, I want the HTTP response to be displayed in place of the form.

Without creating another view to render the response to the submission, is there a way to display the response?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768936/is-it-a-good-practice-to-redirect-after-a-form-has-been-submitted

Comment: I can't say that I've found a definite answer just yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

It's better and a safe practice to redirect to a new page after a successful action.

If you render your response on the POST method, the user can refresh the page and the form will be send it again. If you redirect to another page you will not have that problem.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get for a more detailed argument.

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript instead.

- Users fill in the form.
- Using JavaScript, you perform a POST of the form's contents to a URL and the Django view returns success or failure after the form's contents have been processed. Instead of returning HTML the view could return a JSON response with any information that you need (e.g., an error message).
- If it failed, you can display the error message(s).
- If it was successful, you can remove the form and replace the HTML of the form with a success message.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative / a more global solution, you could consider using the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/).
It is really convenient to use, and make you avoid some extra views.